# Laravel 5.4 Eloquent mass creation

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Given next array, which represents Page model:

```
[
  "en" => [
    "title": "Hello world",
    "content": "Lorem ipsum ...",
    "keyphrases": [
      "Key phrase 1",
      "Key phrase 2"
    ]
  ],
  "es" => [
    "title": "Hola Mundo",
    "content": "Lorem ipsum ...",
    "keyphrases": [
      "Frase clave 1",
      "Frase clave 2"
    ]
  ]
]
```

using `Page::create(...)` will create&save new page record to database, but key phrases are stored in different table (and are represented by "Keyphrase" model), So I tried using `Page::create(...)->keyphrases()->create($request->all())` but it didn't work, because create method only creates one instance, as I understand it.

What is the best approach for mass creation of "keyphrases" in database, considering my data is split into languages?

I don't think it matters, but I am using `dimsav/laravel-translations`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a loop to insert the multiple records. The alternative is splitting the array of the request into an array with subarrays which set the different columns of the table. Like this

```
//Modify the data so that the sturcture is as $keyhrases
$keyhrases = array( [ 'keyphrase' => 'Foo' ], [ 'keyphrase' => 'Bar' ], etc );

$page->keyphrases()->insert($keyhrases);
```

But modifying the array is more work than a simple for loop, again.

Comment: Indeed loop is the right approach in this case, but the complexity was within the need to save english and espaniol under the same array, so I changed keyphrase input name (in HTML) to: keyphrase[$i][$locale][content]

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how you want the keyphrases to be stored. But here's a good example.

```
/*[
    [
        "Key phrase 1",
        "Key phrase 2"
    ],
    [
        "Frase clave 1",
        "Frase clave 2"
    ]
]*/
$keyPhrases = array_column($data, 'keyphrases');

$page = Page::create(...);

$page->keyphrases()->insert($keyPhrases);
```

Comment: Keyphrases are to be stored in a table which contains: id, content, page_id (foreign).

Tried your example but it produces error because laravel expects array index to be field name, not a number..

Comment: That was just an example dataset. Of course i had no idea of what your field names were to give u a good example. But nonetheless the point was that u could use `insert` the way i showed you to do what you asked for.